# How can I redirect old URLs to new URLs using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, seo, http-status-code-404

I am using Prestashop. Recently I decided to change URLs to the shorter look. Usually when I changed something in Traffic & SEO settings, the old addresses redirected me to the new one. In my recent change that did not happened and old URLs give me 404 error. Is it possible to make a rule in htaccess that will redirect all old URLs to new URLs? I have tried some redirect generators but I ended up with Error 500.

Previously my urll was: domain.com/category-name/id-product-name

Now it is: domain.com/iid/product-name

Is it possible to make a rule in htaccess that will change all URLs to new URL style?